# Infinite dimensional Hilbert space is isomorphic to $L^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

In "The Free Markoff Field" by E. Nelson, it is claimed that if $H$ is an infinite-dimensional real Hilbert space, then there is a non-atomic measure space $(K,m)$ such that $L^{2}(K,m)$ is isomorphic to $H$.  How does this work?  I know that if $\{u_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ is a complete orthonormal set, then the Plancherel formula $\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}} \langle x, u_{\alpha}\rangle \langle u_{\alpha},y\rangle$ exhibits a unitary isomorphism between $H$ and $L^{2}(\mathcal{A},c)$, where $c$ is the counting measure.  However, $(\mathcal{A},c)$ is certainly atomic.  Apparently this is untrue if $H$ is finite-dimensional, but it's not obvious to me how to get something better than $(\mathcal{A},c)$ when $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite.

Comment: If $H$ is infinite-dimensional and separable, then it is isomorphic to $L^{2}([0,1])$ with the Lebesgue measure, or $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which ever you like. When not separable, decompose it into a product of separables and use the same isomorphism of each factor with $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then take one more isomorphism between $\otimes L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $L^2(\coprod\mathbb{R})$, where $\coprod\mathbb{R}$ is the disjoint union of copies of $\mathbb{R}$, with the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thanks!  That clears that up.

Answer (score 1):

For $H$ infinite-dimensional and separable, you have $H\simeq L^2[0,1]$ (or, instead of $[0,1]$, you can use any Borel subset of $\mathbb R^n$ of $\mathbb C^n$ with nonempty interior; other choices are possible, too).

When $H$ has dimension higher than countable, by decomposing its basis in a union of countable orthonomal sets we may write $H=\bigoplus_j H_j$, where each $H_j$ is separable. This will be obviusly isomorphic to $\bigoplus _j L^2[0,1]$, and now you can identify this latter space with $L^2(T)$, where $T$ is the disjoint union of copies of $[0,1]$, and the measure is the product measure.

Comment: Hi Martin do you have some reference for the fact that $H\cong L^2[0,1]$? In practice we use the fact that $H\cong \ell^2$ ?

Comment: Isomorphism of Hilbert spaces happens if and only if  cardinality of orthonormal bases coincides. An orthonomal basis of $L^2[0,1]$ is $\{e^{2\pi i k t}\}_{k\in\mathbb Z}$.